# C#: If listbox string equals

Tags: c#, if-statement, listbox

how can I use an if statement like the following?:

```
 if ( listBox6.SelectedItem.ToString = ("hi")) 
{

}
```

I tried that and got the error:

> Cannot assign to 'ToString' because it is a 'method group'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made three mistake,:

1 . You forgot about parantessis of `ToString()` method.

2 . You try to make equality, in fact assigning value to method, should change `=` with `==`.

3 . You forgot null checking may be in future causes to problems.

you can edit it as below:

```
if ( listBox6.SelectedItem != null && listBox6.SelectedItem.ToString() == "hi")
```

Comment: A little of subject but do you know how to make a for loop that if a listbox has an item that for example has the word hi in it it will delete it?

Comment: @user1017524 you can use SelectedIndices property of listBox, and for example if selectedIndices[0] == 5 then you should remove listBox.Items.RemoveAt(5) or listBox.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndices[i])) but important thing is you should use backward loop in this case.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Method invocations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) must have an argument list in parenthesis, even if the list is empty.
2. The [equality operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) is `==`, not to be confused with the [assignment operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) `=`.

So your code should look like this:

```
if (listBox6.SelectedItem.ToString() == "hi")
{
}
```

---

Note that `listBox6.SelectedItem` returns null if there is no currently selected item. Invoking ToString in this case causes a [NullReferenceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) at runtime. It's probably safer to [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) the selected item to string instead:

```
if ((string)listBox6.SelectedItem == "hi")
{
}
```

Comment: A little of subject but do you know how to make a for loop that if a listbox has an item that for example has the word hi in it it will delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(listBox6.SelectedItem.ToString() == "hi") {
}
```